# Graphics framework for 3D flight simulation

Tags: 3d, vector-graphics, opengl, unity

I'm trying to make a basic 3D visual flight simulator that displays terrain and buildings in 3D from the cockpit's perspective. I don't care about the flight physics. This project needs to be completed in a month or so.

The end goal is something like this: [image]

Except with buildings and vegetation and other structures. What framework should I use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Other than a time machine so as get a **lot** more time than 1 month you are going to need something that does it all for you.

I would suggest using the [Godot](https://godotengine.org/) game engine. The actual development language can be C++, C# (using Mono), GDScript or one of the community supported languages.

- It is **free**, gratis & open source with a permissive *MIT* licence
- Cross Platform *Works on Windows, macOS, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Haiku.*
- Built in editor with syntax highlighting
- Multi-lingual
- 3D or 2D game creation

I recommend starting from the manuals Getting Started step by step [guide](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/index.html).